# Finite Difference Method Neumann Boundary Condition with Variable Coefficients

Tags: finite-difference, boundary-conditions

*Disclaimer*

In the process of typing up this question, I determine its solution.  Since I went through the trouble of typing up the question in its entirety, I will post its answer as well.  It may help out others who find themselves in the same predicament.  Think of this as a sort of blog-post, if you will.

**The Goal**

Consider the mixed boundary value problem
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(k(x)\frac{du}{dx}\right)=f \text{ in }\Omega\\
u=P \text{ at } x=0\\
\frac{du}{dx}=T \text{ at } x=1
\end{align}
where $P$ and $T$ are constants and $f$ is a source term.

I'm using finite differences and my goal is to impose the boundary condition at $x=1$ in such a way as to achieve second order accuracy.  Assume that the grid has $N+1$ equispaced points (including the boundary points) given as $x_0,x_1,...,x_N$

**My Approach**

At the right boundary, use a 2nd order centered difference for the boundary condition
\begin{equation}
\frac{u_{N+1}-u_{N-1}}{\Delta x}=T\end{equation}

and the 2nd derivative operator as:
\begin{align}
\frac{k_{N+\frac{1}{2}}\frac{u_{N+1}-u_{N}}{\Delta x} -k_{N-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{u_{N}-u_{N-1}}{\Delta x}}{\Delta x}=f_i\end{align}

We can solve for the ghost point $U_{N+1}$ in the 1st equation, substitute it into the 2nd equation and simplify.

**The Problem**

Using this discretization requires the evaluation of $k_{N+\frac{1}{2}}=k(x_N+\frac{\Delta x}{2})$, which is outside of the domain!  In general, $k(x)$ is only defined within the domain and I can't/shouldn't use values outside of it.  Thus, I don't think this is the right approach to achieve 2nd order accuracy.  What else can I do in this case?

Comment: The physically correct boundary conditions for this equation are $k \partial u/\partial x=T$ and this is how you should discretize it.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth:  Very true.  If the boundary condition were given as $k(x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=T$, then would it be advisable to multiply $k(x_N)$ to the discretization below?

Comment: You mean to the formula below "My approach"? If so, yes!

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: Actually, I was referring to the discretization technique in my answer, not the question :)

Comment: Yes, there too.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about discretizing the 2nd derivative operator since it requires evaluating at points outside the domain.  Instead, just adjust the stencil for the boundary condition to use points $u_{N},u_{N-1},$ and $u_{N-2}$.  By using standard *method of undetermined coefficients*, you can produce the coefficients necessary to achieve 2nd order accuracy.  If i'm not mistaken, the discretized boundary condition in this case turn out to produce

$$\frac{du}{dx}\approx\frac{-\frac{1}{2}u_{N-2} +2u_{N-1} -\frac{3}{2}u_N}{\Delta x}=T$$

Comment: It appears you missed a sign in your equation.  I'm assuming it's positive, but since you have obviously done the derivation more recently than me, I will let you correct it.

Comment: @GodricSeer: Indeed!  I have adjusted it.