# Neumann boundary condition FD implementation for instationnary diffusion equation

Tags: finite-difference, boundary-conditions, diffusion

I am trying to solve this diffusion equation :
$\dfrac{\partial D\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{\partial x}+S = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ ($D$ is not constant and varies according to $x$) with the following BC: $f(x,0)=1 , f(0,t)=0, \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(1,t)=0$

I am using a central finite difference scheme (2nd order) for space and Euler explicit for time (1st order). 
The discretized $[0..1]$ domain contains the $x_{i}$ points, $i \in [0..N]$ 
 ($x_{0}=0 , x_{N}=1$).

The implementation of Dirichlet condition at $x=0$ is simple.
For the Neumann boundary condition, I saw a lot of references that treated simple cases, adequate for constant diffusion coefficients and stationnary cases, like the ghost point, that I can't consider in my case(Diffusion coefficient can't be evaluated out of the domain, ghost point envolves evaluation the equation on a point that is not inside the interior domain... ).

So I am trying something at my own and I want confirmation or correction if I omitted an important aspect in my work:

The discretized equation evaluated at $x_{N-1}$ involves the value of $f_{N}$. If we had Diricihlet condition at $x_{N}$, the problem would have been solved directly. But in our case, $f_{N}$ is unknown.

What I did is that I treated the Neumann BC  with a backward scheme (at the 2nd order to preserve the general order of the whole scheme) in order to have an expression of $f^{k}_{N}$:

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_{N},k\Delta t)=\dfrac{-3f^{k}_{N}+4f^{k}_{N-1}-f^{k}_{N-2}}{2\Delta x}=0$

$f^{k}_{N}=4/3 f^{k}_{N-1}-1/3 f^{k}_{N-2}$

then I injected the new expression of $f^{k}_{N}$ in the discretized equation at $x_{N-1}$. Meaning that I did not add an equation to the problem as I would do for a stationnary problem but I injected the expression of $f^{k}_{N}$ inside the last equation.

So the unknown vector $f^{k}$ in a case of matrix writing would only contain $f^{k}_{i}, i\in [1..N-1]$ (like in a full Dirichlet situation)

Is it correct ?

For information, the matrix form of the discretized problem is :
$f^{k+1}=Af^{k}+S+B$, with $B$ the vector containing the B.C , and $S$ the 2nd member vector

Comment: Note that I solved the stationary problem adding a line in the resolution matrix related to the unknown $f_{N}$ containing the Backward finite difference 2nd order discretization at the boundary and worked fine. But I couldn't do the same for an unstationary problem.

Comment: The treatment of the stationary problem is presented here :
https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/7688/finite-difference-method-neumann-boundary-condition-with-variable-coefficients

Comment: Yes It is correct. What you said: "A full dirichlet situation" does not imply that you have a square matrix of size $N-1$. At the end you must have $N+1$ equations, in this case one is imposed at the beginning (Dirichlet) and the other is calculated once the system is solved (Neumann). Therefore it is not a "full Dirichlet situation",otherwise the boundary values would have been known "a priori".

Comment: @HBR Thanks for your reply. What I mean by a full Dirichlet situation is when the Neumann condition is also replaced by a Dirichlet condition (2 Dirichlet condition for the whole problem , at $x=0$ and at $x=1$). In this case $f^{k}_{N} $ is known, and the problem  square matrix has a size of $N-1$ $(N+1-2)$. Now in the case of a Neumann boundary for $x_{N}$ we have to add an equation in the last line of the matrix for $f^{k}_{N} $ is unknown and I don't see how to express it in the unstationary case.

Comment: This is not a Dirichlet BC is a Neumann BC. You think (wrong) that it is Dirichlet because you can obtain an explicit solution for this node. A Dirichlet BD is an imposed value, which does not depend on other solves variables...

Comment: @HBR, I am sorry but I think I did not understand you. In my question when I mentionned the case of a Dirichlet condition at the point $x_{N}$ it was only to point out the difference with a Neumann condition that will envolve adding a new equation for the new unknown point.

Comment: In fact... you added one additional equation for the unkown point... but instead of being solved with the others... you have decided to solve it appart. What is more, what you have done here is the same procedure that one must follow to solve for a "ghost point".

Comment: @HBR Actually the added equation was injected in the matrix system, and therefore it is not solved apart, plus I don't see how I am following the "ghost point" procedure as I did not create a new point outside the domain.

Comment: So If you have put this equation in your system you should have $[1,...,N]$ unknowns... anyways... I told you that this is not a Dirichlet BC... if you don't agree please do an easy search on google... On the other hand... you are treating the last node as a "ghost point". Because it's been excluded from the system.